# Starting STAF on boot of windows machine

Tags: service, staf

Hi I have installed STAF "http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/staf/STAF3419-setup-winamd64.exe?download" on my windows 2008 server machine. By default STAF is getting started at Logon. I want to start STAF as soon as I boot may machine. How can I change this setting?

Comment: Providing a link to a download page isn't the most friendly of actions. Does the project/software not have a more inert, descriptive page that you could link to?

Answer (score 0):

I did it in windows way not STAF:
1. In the Search box, type control userpasswords2, and then press ENTER.  Administrator permission required If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
2. Clear the Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer check box, and then click Apply.
3. In the Automatically Log On dialog box, type your password, and then click OK.
4. In the User Accounts dialog box, click OK.